# Laravel Mail use bootstrap in blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I want to manage mail body layout using bootstrap, can we use bootstrap there ?

```
Mail::send('emails.momentData'),function ($message) use ($mailIds,$studentName) {
    $message->from();
    $message->subject();
    $message->to();
});
```

so i want to use bootstrap in `emails.momentData.blade.php` file.
how can i do it ??

i tried using bootstrap css in head section , but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: you can get idea how to integrate bootstrap in blade template
https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-laravel-layouts-using-blade

Comment: i have user bootstrap before but in this case i am unable to use boottrap in `emails.momentData.blade.php` file

Comment: So what you have done so far, Show code

Comment: bootstrap doesn't apply there